# Liferay "current URL/robots.txt : No VirtualHost" Exception

Tags: tomcat, liferay, virtualhost, robots.txt

Hello community i worked the last days intensiv on the implementation of opensocial into liferay, but as i am new to the liferay portal and the portal documentation is pretty bad, i have a few questions left.

How do i have to configure the VirtualHost for Opensocial, which Callback Url is right? (An example for twitter would help me a lot.)

I use Liferay Tomcat with Eclipse and currently Version 6.1-b4. Its the Liferay 6.1 Beta to be more specific i edited the following part:

1. Installed 6.1-b4 from Trunk
2. Installed opensocial-portlet-6.1.0.1-ce-b4-20111110.war
3. Changed HTTP1.1 from 8080 to 80
4. Changed "shindig.signing.viewer-access-tokens-enabled=false" to "true", in shindig.properties
5. Changed "shindig.signing.global-callback-url=http://*************/opensocial-portlet/gadgets/oauthcallback"
6. Added "http://code.google.com/p/opensocialdeju/source/browse/Twitter/TwitterDemo.xml?r=11" to gadgets editor
7. Added Consumer and Secret from Twitter to the gadget "Oauth preferences"
8. Added the gadget to a page.
9. Added "http://*************/opensocial-portlet/gadgets/oauthcallback" to the Twitter settings for the Callback URL

I can click on the "Personalize this gadget" and get a Twitter popup.
The gadget shows now:"Please click I've approved access once you've approved access to your data. "
If i approve access i get the Error : "Error: 403 Error, OAuth error: UNKNOWN_PROBLEM, Client state belongs to a different person (state owner=G-10180, pageViewer=10196) ==== Original request: GET /1/account/verify_credentials.json Host: api.twitter.com X-Shindig-AuthType: oauth X-Forwarded-For: ***.***.***.*** X-shindig-dos: on ===="

So in the end i stand in front of many different URLs and have no clue how to configure the VirtualHost , so that it is possible to get a AccessToken.

This was only the first part, then i need to edit the robots.txt to allow Twitter etc. to send me the Token, then i am done i guess :).

Answer (score 0):

yes Liferay lacks proper documentation, but community resources (blogs & wikis) are quite useful.

Did you take a look at [this](http://www.liferay.com/web/dennis.ju/blog/-/blogs/6979953)

Comment: Sure i looked at this tutorial, but it is not what i am looking for. I try to be bit more specific, I downloaded the 6.1-b4 Version from the liferay trunk and installed the opensocial 6.1-b4.war then i changed the HTTP/1.1 from 8080 to 80 and changed "shindig.signing.viewer-access-tokens-enabled=false" to "true". Are there any more steps to enable Oauth support for opensocial?
Here is a link to show you the error message:http://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11651762